# Clear textbox in Javascript checking against checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox, dynamics-crm-2011, xrm

I have some javascript controlling the logic on an MS dynamics 2011 form.

When I click a checkbox (checked by default) There is a textbox which allows you to input data.  When I uncheck this box, the textbox disappears.  However, When I recheck the checkbox, the textbox reappears (as desired) but still has any text that was inputted previously, still stored.  How can I ensure the textbox is set to null?  Code snippet included.

Thanks.

```
function SetupForm() {
     debugger;
     HA_OtherText();
 }

 function HA_OtherText() {
     Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ha_other").getValue();
     if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ha_other").getValue() == true) {
         Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("ha_othertext").setVisible(true);
     } else {
         Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("ha_othertext").setVisible(false);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you're doing is setting the field to visible or visible, you'll need to set the field value to null if you want to "clear" it:

```
function HA_OtherText()
{
  Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ha_other").getValue();
  if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ha_other").getValue() == true) 
  {
    Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("ha_othertext").setVisible(true);
  }
  else
  {
    Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("ha_othertext").setVisible(false);
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ha_othertext").setValue(null);
  }
}
```